# MDC with Lettuce's RedisFuture

Tags: lettuce

I am using lettuce-core 6.2.6.RELEASE with Kotlin 1.9.10.

I'm currently using lettuce to subscribe to channels and would like to log with the parent thread's  MDC context when a message is received from Redis.

Anyone know if this is possible with the current implementation of lettuce?

I'm curious if there's a way to update this code in order to pass the MDC values to it.

```
val client = RedisClient.create(this.config.target)
val connection: StatefulRedisPubSubConnection<String, String> = client.connectPubSub()
connection.addListener(listener)

val async = connection.async()

val futureSub = async.subscribe(this.config.channels[0])
futureSub.await()
```